# Set multiple amount for cart rule in single coupon code

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes, magento2.3.5-p2

I want to set multiple discount amount for cart rule in single coupon code

> Example : If TEST10% coupon has 10 amount and if i apply this coupon
> code then after deduction on subtotal i want to deduct custom amount
> like 20 OR 30 as well

I want to achieve this with plugin or observer, Please guide me for same

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-multiple-coupons/

Comment: @Bojjaiah I want apply multiple coupon amount in single coupon code , this extension is applying multiple coupon code